# dynamic add input in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new at javascript and I need some help making sense of this code and why it's not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input id="in" type="text" name="name">
    </form>
    <button id="add">addone</button>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#add').click(function() {
          $('#in').append('<br /><input type="text" name="name">');
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to append another html input but I have no ideas why it's not working!?.

Comment: An `input` has no children

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An input is self-closing, it has no children, and you can't append to it.

You can however insert something **after** it

```
$('#in').after('<br /><input type="text" name="name">');
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input id="in" type="text" name="name">
    </form>
    <button id="add">addone</button>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $('#add').click(function() {
        $('#in').after('<br /><input type="text" name="name">');
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that your duplicating the name, and depending on what you indend to do with it, using `name[]` could be a good idea ?